# React firebase cloud functions with many return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

There is any way to set my `updateQuestions` variable inside a foreach + ref ? Or i must do two different cloud functions ? I want to return a giant update `updateQuestions` but i need to return data from a foreach based on a firebase data..

here is my function :

```
exports.deleteQuestion = functions.database.ref('questions_for_mars/{pushId}').onDelete(event => {
      const original = event.val()
      idQuestion = event.key
      authorQuestion = original.author
      //console.log('event', original.answers)

      return admin.database().ref('counter/questions_active').once('value').then((snapshot) => {


        var questions_active = snapshot.val()

        var updateQuestions = {};



        updateQuestions['/counter/questions_active'] = questions_active - 1
        updateQuestions['/my_questions/' + authorQuestion + '/' + idQuestion] = null
        updateQuestions['/my_questions_send/' + authorQuestion + '/' + idQuestion] = null
        updateQuestions['/questions/' + idQuestion] = null
        //updateQuestions['/my_answers/' + authorQuestion + '/' + idQuestion] = null



        event.child('answers').forEach(child => {


          var mars = child.key

          return admin.database().ref('/mars/' + mars + '/counter/answers_active').once('value').then((snapshot) => {

            var answers_active = snapshot.val()

            updateQuestions['/my_answers/' + mars + '/' + idQuestion] = null
            updateQuestions['/mars/' + mars + '/counter/answers_active'] = answers_active - 1


          });

          console.log('TOTO', updateQuestions)
        });
        console.log('UPDAYE', updateQuestions)

        return admin.database().ref().update(updateQuestions)

      })


    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using an old version of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff. You should definitely update it (see instructions in this doc).

Then, for your `event.child('answers').forEach(child => {})` loop, you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to manage the parallel asynchronous queries to the database.

You will receive the results of `Promise.all()` in an array corresponding to the fulfillment values in the same order than the queries array.

So the following code should do the trick (untested):

```
exports.deleteQuestion = functions.database.ref('questions_for_mars/{pushId}').onDelete((snapshot, context) => {
    const original = snapshot.val()
    idQuestion = snapshot.key
    authorQuestion = original.author
    //console.log('event', original.answers)

    var updateQuestions = {};

    return admin.database().ref('counter/questions_active').once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {

            var questions_active = snapshot.val();

            updateQuestions['/counter/questions_active'] = questions_active - 1
            updateQuestions['/my_questions/' + authorQuestion + '/' + idQuestion] = null
            updateQuestions['/my_questions_send/' + authorQuestion + '/' + idQuestion] = null
            updateQuestions['/questions/' + idQuestion] = null
            //updateQuestions['/my_answers/' + authorQuestion + '/' + idQuestion] = null

            var queries = [];

            snapshot.child('answers').forEach(child => {
                var mars = child.key
                queries.push(admin.database().ref('/mars/' + mars + '/counter/answers_active').once('value'))
            });

            return Promise.all(queries);
        })
        .then(results => {
            results.forEach(snapshot => {
                var answers_active = snapshot.val()
                //Here you need to extract the value of mars from snapshot.key
                //I let you do this piece of code!! 
                updateQuestions['/my_answers/' + mars + '/' + idQuestion] = null
                updateQuestions['/mars/' + mars + '/counter/answers_active'] = answers_active - 1
            });
            return admin.database().ref().update(updateQuestions)
        });

})
```

Comment: not working updateQuestions not getting the queries

Comment: Note that I made an update. Check that you use the last version.

Comment: the thing is queries stay empty ?